# Are questions related to phonemes on topic?

Tags: discusión

I'm interested in what are the phonemes for the sounds **g**, **c**, **z** and **s** in Latino American Spanish as in **g**itano, tren**c**ito, **z**orro and ca**s**a, respectively. Also I'd like to know the classification of those sounds, for instance fricatives, affricates, etc.

Is this on topic on SE for Spanish language, or is it better suited for the linguistics site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former yes, but my guess is you're looking for the phones themselves, as the phonemes are the same across the Spanish speaking world.

The latter is more appropriate to linguistics.SE because it is general to all languages

Comment: I see, I'll make two separate questions then, one for each site.